# Swift: "with" before parameter in a function

Tags: swift, function, parameters

I would want to as you term of "with" in Swift.

For example, sometimes I see piece of code like this:

```
public func configure(with imageName: String) {
  myImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
}
```

In here, before the parameter name, there is a term as "with". However, I could not find anything about it on the internet. I am sure that it should be but when I write to google "Swift Function (with parameter)" or sth like that, google doesn't bring me anything.

Is there anybody who knows the purpose of the "with" before the parameter in Swift?

Thank you.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33637264/1187415

Comment: It has no inherent meaning. It's just an arbitrary external label, forcing the _caller_ to say the label when making a call, i.e. `configure(with: ...)`. You can declare any external label you want: `func configure(wackawacka imageName: String)` would be just as legal. You might try reading the docs: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID166 This is _extremely_ basic, so it's worth looking it up before resorting to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called external parameter name. the main purpose of it sentence formulation and make it easy for reader. can read more about [Parameter Names](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID166) from official documentation.

Comment: Thanks, When I see this "with" in different times in different project, I supposed that it is a Swift term. Thank you. What a silly question. :)

Comment: Most welcome, never mind.